# Help with basic diary/calendar features

Tags: org-agenda, calendar

I have created two diary entries, I can't see them in the week agenda. Why is that? Also I would have expected 11/15 to be highlighted, or something like that, to indicate an event was planned that day.

[image: Weekly]
[image: Cal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know Org Agenda can work with Diary since they are two separate apps. Then I searched the org manual with keyword `diary`, and found this on [(info "(org) Weekly/daily agenda")](http://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html):

> In order to include entries from the Emacs diary into Org mode’s
>   agenda, you only need to customize the variable
>
> ```
> (setq org-agenda-include-diary t)
> ```

That variable defaults to nil.

Comment: Now that the diary entries come up in the agenda, I would have thought `M-x org-agenda-to-appt` would produce something. I get, instead, "no event to add". What are events, then?

Comment: @Erwann hmm, I can't help. I am not familiar with org-agenda/diary.